# Why does JSON.NET serialize everything on a single line?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I simply want the JSON.net serializer to write out JSON objects (to file), **one object per line** but instead it just appends everything on the same top line. All of the JSON.net samples seem to imply that what I want is default behavior but I'm not seeing it work that way. Here's code:

```
static void EtwToJsonHelper(TraceEvent data, JsonSerializer s, JsonTextWriter jw)
{
    var names = data.PayloadNames;

    jw.WriteStartObject();
    jw.WritePropertyName("TimeStamp");
    jw.WriteValue(data.TimeStamp);
    ...
    jw.WriteEndObject();
}
```

Output looks like this:
{object}{obj2}...{objN} all on a single line.

But I want:

{obj1}

{obj2}

...

How do I do this?

Comment: It seems silly to care about the specific formatting of the JSON.. Where such specific formatting is required, there are "JSON pretty formatters/printers" that can be applied for the specific (human) consumption.

Comment: It's for Hive, not humans. Hive naturally expects single record/object per line.

Comment: That "naturally" makes me sad :( It's like "naturally" expecting expecting empty white-space between XML elements. But, I guess you need what you need ..

Comment: Is this truly the simplest way to serialize TraceEvent to JSON?

Answer (score 17):

The samples provided are indented for clarity, but the default behavior is to write the resulting JSON string without any unnecessary whitespace. You can override this behavior like this:

```
jw.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
jw.WriteStartObject();
...
```

**Further Reading**

- [`Formatting` enum](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Formatting.htm)

---

To ensure that each entry is appended to a new line, you could simply write a new line character after you've written your JSON object, like this:

```
...
jw.WriteEndObject();
jw.WriteRaw("\n");
```

Or by calling [`WriteLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ywxh2328) on the underlying `TextWriter`, though that would need to be done outside of this method.

Comment: Should've mentioned that I don't want indented JSON because that puts new lines within the object and it's KVP's; I just want a new line per object. Hive likes JSON like that.

Comment: @jeking I see. See my updated answer for some options on how to do that.

Comment: Hah! Thanks buddy, I came to the same result and posted my answer. Looks like you beat me to it, though.

Comment: @jeking No problem. There are usually multiple solutions to these kinds of problems. +1 for posting your answer as an alternative.

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out, though not sure if there's a cleaner way. I added a

```
jw.WriteWhitespace(Environment.NewLine);
```

at the end. Now everything looks good:

{"TimeStamp":"2014-03-10T15:04:27.0128185",...}
{"TimeStamp":"2014-03-10T15:04:27.0128185",...}
...